# Dynamic text from XML in Flash with Actionscript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cc

I'm quite new to Flash and I'm searching for a solution to an error I get.

I've got an XML-file called "import.xml" and I want some information from it into a dynamic text field. Everytime I try I get an error 1009.

In the .FLA file i've got a dynamic text box at frame 60 with the instancename "txt_receptnaam"

Can anyone help me with my problem? Thank You!

I'm working with a separate .AS-file and this is the code:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader; 
    import flash.net.URLLoader;

    public class applicatie extends MovieClip {


        public function applicatie() {
            trace("Hello world!");

            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("import.xml");
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, importComplete);
            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
        }

        public function importComplete(e:Event) {
            var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
            txt_receptnaam.text = myXML.info.name  + " is nu geopend!";
        }
    }

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at applicatie/importComplete()[.../applicatie.as:24]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Comment: can you give as a sample line of your xml ?

Comment: It's not clear whether it's your XML object or your TextField that is NULL and throwing the error. Put a trace statement after the line var myXML:XML... trace(txt_receptnaam, myXML); so you know which variable is throwing the error.